# How to check existance of category name and parent ID in database using PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to check the existence of a category in the database with the same name and same parent ID received as parameters from a form to create a new category.

So basically,
Parameters received from form:

1. Category name
2. Category slug
3. Parent ID of an already existing category
4. Category description

I need to check if there is already a category with the same

1. Category name
2. Parent ID

I've already written a function for it but it doesn't seem to work.

```
foreach(Category::all() as $c) {
        if($c->name === $request->name) {
            if($c->parent_id === $request->parent_id) {
                return redirect(route('admin.products.categories'))->with([
                    'error' => 'A term with the name provided already exists.'
                ]);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }  else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

I'm a noob at Laravel and PHP so I think I'm having trouble properly breaking out of the foreach loop.

Appreciate the help and please don't be brutal with your reply if you find a similar question to mine here at Stack overflow. I couldn't find any.

Comment: What happens when you remove the else breaks?

Comment: same. It lets the data pass through and registers to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily, try:

```
if(Category::where('name', $request->name)->where('parent_id', $request->parent_id)->get())
{
   return redirect(route('admin.products.categories'))->with([
     'error' => 'A term with the name provided already exists.'
   ]);
}
```

Comment: I tried it an now it doesn't let me through at all. I mean no data is being entered at all. Just returning the error message.

Comment: Nice to here that.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform that by defining the validator in which you specify all rules to validate data that come from your form.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|unique:categories:name',
    'slug' => 'required|unique:categories:slug',
    'parent_id' => 'required|unique:categories:parent_id',
]);
```

The unique rule take as parameters the name of table and the column on which to check `unique:table_name:column_name`

And to check that the data with which to create a new category match your rule you must just do this

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect(route('admin.products.categories'))->with([
        'error' => 'A term with the name provided already exists.'
    ]);

    // Or you can pass the validator to 
    return redirect(route('admin.products.categories'))
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->with('error' => 'A term with the name provided already exists.')
                ->withInput();
}
```

when you pass to `withErrors` the `$validator` it will allow you to access all error that come from your validator